# VB.NET Get everything from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

Is there a method to get all non-empty data currently in DataGridView, other than iterating through row/columns indexes? "Get" as in pump it all in array/vector or most conveniently matrix.
I'd like to do this as quickly as possible and don't care about the order of items, would Parallel.ForEach be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, the magic is in Casting :)
(DataGridView is name of my object, not the type)

```
Parallel.ForEach(DataGridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow), _
        Sub(currentRow)
            Parallel.ForEach(currentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell), _
                   Sub(currentCell)
                       // do stuff
                   End Sub)
        End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stab in the dark not knowing what's in your DataGridView numbers of rows/columns?

I would try LINQ first

```
Dim x = From Thing in DataGridViewReference Where Thing <> "" select Thing
```

If you know the type that can be developed into

```
Dim x as list(of String) = (From Thing in DataGridViewReference Where Thing <> "" select Thing).tolist
```

And for speed

```
Dim x as list(of String) = (From Thing in DataGridViewReference Where Thing <> "" select Thing).ToList.AsParallel
```

Tim

Comment: My DataGridView will contain variable amount of inputs from user or it's contents will be loaded from file (which can be big).
I have trouble with "DataGridViewReference" as I can't find any way to directly dump collection of Items (Cells), so I don't have to iterate row -> cells in it -> next row.